# How to configure freeradius to allow whitespaces in username

Tags: freeradius

We got some usernames with whitespaces at the end and they are getting rejected by freeradius. Does anyone know how to configure it so that these username don't get rejected?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The default virtual server in `raddb/sites-enabled/default` contains a call to the `filter_username` policy (see the top of the `authorize` section).

This policy is defined in `raddb/policy.d/filter`, and makes several checks to ensure the username is sane. The first of which ensures no spaces.

You can:

- Remove the call to `filter_username` entirely from the virtual server; or
- Alter the policy so that it doesn't check for spaces; or
- Fix the devices so that the username is correct.

The last option is the correct one. You will likely find that if you permit usernames with spaces then they will fail to authenticate anyway (they are not valid usernames) - so it will be the same outcome, yet wasting more server resources in the process. The filter tests are there for a reason.